# Case is only returning the Else statement

Tags: vba, excel

When I run my case it only returns the Else statement for every line. I know that the case should work because when I test it on one cell like "D2" only it returned the correct data. It is only when I try to use this case within a loop that I get all zeros. I have tried researching several things and have not been able to make the code work right. However I am very new to VBA as all I had was some light experience with JavaScript prior to receiving this project... Please help.

```
Dim account As Range
Dim i As Long

Set account = Range("D2:D1100")
For Each cell In account

    If cell.Value Then

        Dim acctNum As Integer, result4 As Integer

            Select Case acctNum

               Case 1110
                    result = 105010

                Case 2710
                    result = 205000

                Case 2750
                    result = 205010

                Case 3110
                    result = 401100

                Case 3115
                    result = 401110

                Case 3120
                    result = 401120

                Case Else
                    result = 0

            End Select
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = result
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You don't assign any value to acctNum

Comment: I have to be honest I have no idea what I am doing as this is my first week with VBA... I have had to research and cannibalize every last piece of code thus far. So forgive me if I as a dumb question like what value should I assign to acctNum? And do you mean something like acctNum = XX? And where exactly do I put this assignment?

Comment: Well you're selecting the case of the value of `acctNum`, so where is it located? Before you can give a value to `result`, you have to test against something first.

Comment: Okay that makes sense I thought I was testing it against Range("D2:D1100"). But I guess that only applied to account. So I need something like Set acctNum = Range("D2:D1100")?

Comment: `acctNum =cell.Value`

Comment: That worked! I would like to kiss all three of you on the face! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have revised your code below and it works as expected. I would recommend using arrays for this type of work, but that's something for you to look into later when you're more comfortable with VBA.

The errors you were having have been pointed out by others, and I have fixed a couple that you would have found later.

For values over 32000, you want to use Long rather than Integer (it's not exactly 32000, but if you're anywhere close to that number, just use Long)

I don't think it's worth using acctNum so I took that out, and you Dim 'i' but then don't use it, so I have removed that too.

```
Dim account As Range
Dim result As Long

Set account = Range("D2:D1100")
For Each cell In account

    If cell.Value Then

        Select Case cell.Value

            Case 1110
                result = 105010

            Case 2710
                result = 205000

            Case 2750
                result = 205010

            Case 3110
                result = 401100

            Case 3115
                result = 401110

            Case 3120
                result = 401120

            Case Else
                result = 0

        End Select
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = result
End If
Next
```

Comment: You're welcome. When your reputation gets high enough to unlock voting abilities, don't forget to upvote the answers that you found helpful to make it easier for other people to find them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the variable `acctNum` a value. As it stands now you just create the variable so it has no value by the time it is used. See below.

```
Dim acctNum As Integer, result4 As Integer ' You've created the variable here

Select Case acctNum 'And here you're trying to use it but it hasn't been given a value yet
```

Instead if you give it a value before the `Select Case` section your code will provide results you're looking for:

```
Dim acctNum As Integer, result4 As Integer ' You've created the variable here

acctNum = 2710

Select Case acctNum 'And now the variable has a value and should hit the '2710' case
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Note that here I just assigned it a hard-coded value of '2710'. You can pull that value from a cell (e.g. acctNum = cell.Value)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like this:

```
Dim account As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim acctNum As Integer, result4 As Integer

Set account = Range("D2:D1100")

For Each cell In account.Cells

    If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case 1110
                result = 105010
            Case 2710
                result = 205000
            Case 2750
                result = 205010
            Case 3110
                result = 401100
            Case 3115
                result = 401110
            Case 3120
                result = 401120
            Case Else
                result = 0
        End Select
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = result
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand where misunderstanding might lay.

Where you say `Select Case acctNum` this means that each individual `case` will be evaluated against `acctNum` on a `True/ False` basis. For example:

Does `1110` evaluate as `True` against `acctNum`? No... So next Case.

Does `2710` evaluate as `True` against `acctNum`? No... etc, until you hit your else statement.

The reason these are all evaluating as `False` is because you haven't assigned a value to `acctNum` therefore you're not *really* evaluating against anything.

As outlined in an answer above, if you change what you're evaluating against, you will get your expected output.

`Select Case cells.value` - Now you're evaluating your `cases` against cells within your `account` range

Comment: Thank you. That was a meaningful explanation.